# Numeric attributes are being alpha-sorted in ggnet2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggnetwork

I've built a dependency graph using ggnet2 and am trying to set the size of the vertex based on Cost, which is a numeric attribute in the node data structure.

[image]

The issue is calling the method `set.vertex.attribute`.

```
x = data.frame(ID = network.vertex.names(deps))
for (i in names(df)) {
  y = merge(x, df, by = "ID", sort = F)[,i]
  set.vertex.attribute(deps, i, as.character(y))
}
```

If I passing an integer, it complains that `Inappropriate value given in set.vertex.attribute`. A similar issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574757/r-vertex-attributes-inappropriate-value-given-in-set-vertex-attribute)

Comment: Please provide example data and code.

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the loop and add the attribute for the whole vector, all is well.

```
set.vertex.attribute(deps, "Cost", df$Cost)
```